# Get company name form Content Provider in android using new API's

Tags: android

Currently I am getting company name using following code

```
public class ContactsDemo extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.Organizations.CONTENT_URI, 
            null, null, null, null);
    //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.
    if(cursor!=null){
        System.out.println(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                (Contacts.Organizations.COMPANY)));
    }}}
```

but I don't want to use deprected API's.
& in new API's there is no CONTENT_URI in Organisation class.
How to get company name using new API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query the [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) and use these aliases http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.html