# Get the company name of contact in android?

Tags: android, cursor, android-cursoradapter

Hi  i am doing a app on contact app i got the contact id and the Display name using the below code now what i want is the company name alone with the contact id and the display name.how can i get the Company name?

```
    private void populateContactList() {
    // Build adapter with contact entries

    Cursor cursor = getContacts();
    fields = new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID};



    contactqueryAdaptor = new Contactquery_adaptor(this, R.layout.row,
            cursor, fields, new int[] { R.id.applese });




}
```

//getContacts()

```
    private Cursor getContacts() {
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
            + (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";


    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
            sortOrder);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this: [Get company name form Content Provider in android using new API's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553044/get-company-name-form-content-provider-in-android-using-new-apis), you'll need to query the ContactsContract.Data and use these aliases http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.html

Comment: can you say what is the coloumn name of company in android contact?

Comment: I can't test this at the moment, but I would guess you'd need to include `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY` in your `projection` and `fields` arrays?